# Как могу это сократить или записать все в одной функции if (***)

Tags: javascript

```
if (guess == location1) {
    hits = hits + 1;
} else if (guess == location2) {
    hits = hits + 1;
} else if (guess == location3) {
    hits = hits + 1;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ if это оператор, а не  функция

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(guess==loc1 || guess==loc2 || guess==loc3) h++;
```

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно этот участок кода

```
hits+=[location1,location2,location3].includes(guest)
```

Comment: При таком коде коллеги могут подумать что вы ждёте от includes число. Лучше `if( [location1,location2,location3].includes(guest) ) hits++`

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Булева хорошо конвертируется в число: `true` = `1`, `false` = `0`, `1*0` = `0`.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev даже просто `+true`=`1`, `+false`=`0`

Comment: Еще хороший пример на это же направление конвертации: `const daysInMonth=(year,month)=>28+(62648012+16*!(year%4)>>month*2&3);`

Comment: То, что хорошо конвертируется, не значит что так писать нужно. Бывает даже Boolean() пишут вместо !! , потому что мы делаем приведение к булеву, а не двойное отрицание. У вас обфусцированный код, при котором нужно тратить время чтобы гадать, и в итоге решить что вы думаете что там будет число.

Comment: Да это разве обфусцированный код. Вот в [посте dwitter](https://www.dwitter.net/d/20584) обфусцированный код.

Comment: там скорее брейнфак )